# ViewModels with SelectList Design Decison

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, viewmodel

I have created a viewmodel

```
public VMPosition
{
        public VMPosition(){}//for model binder  
        public VMPosition(int EmployeeID)
        {
            PositionStatusList = new SelectList(_repo.getStatuses);
            //populate other properties
        }
        public int CurrentPositionID { get; set; }
        public int EmployeeID { get; set; }
        public int CurrentPositionHistoryID { get; set; }
        public bool AddingNew { get; set; }
        public bool ClosingCurrent { get; set; }
        public string CurrentPosition { get; set; }
        public DateTime CurrentPositionStartDate { get; set; }
        public string ReasonForDeparture { get; set; }
        public SelectList PositionStatusList { get; set; }

}
```

My GET ActionResult is defined as

```
public ActionResult UpdatePosition(int id)
{
     return View(new VMPosition(id)); 
}
```

My POST actionresult is defined as

```
 public ActionResult UpdatePosition(int id, VMPosition Position)
    {
        if(ModelState.IsValid){
             Position Current = new Position{Position.Title etc..}
             //save to db
             return redirectToAction("someAction");
         }
         return View(Position);//here is the problem
    }
```

My SelectList is populated in a constructor that accepts one parameter. Modelbinder cannot and should not call the constructor if the modelstate is invalid. I will have to return the View with model object (which in this case don't contain SelectList value). How can handle this scenario when using view Models.

I can manually populate these values in actionresult but that will violate the DRY principle. However, for the purposes of this question, I'd like help addressing the bigger design question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When dealing with dropdowns in my viewmodels, I usually have a single property associated with the selected list item's value and I have a property that returns a list of selectlistitems.  Then, I use Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ValueProperty, Model.DropDownValues) to render the dropdown.

I imagine in your scenario, you don't have a value corresponding to the selected listitem's value?

Edit: Here's an example from one of my apps...

```
public class MyVM
{
  public int MyObjectId { get; set; }

  public List<SelectListItem> MyObjectList
  {
    get
    {
      List<SelectListItem> list = (from o in MyObjects select new SelectListItem 
        { Value = o.ObjectId.ToString(), Text = o.ObjectName }).ToList();
      list.Insert(0, new SelectListItem 
        { Value = "0", Text = "[Select an object]" });
      return list;
    }
  }
}

<%: Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.MyObjectId, Model.MyObjectList)%>
```

You might have noticed the LINQ query that populates the list.  In this example, I have a list (MyObjects) that was already populated by AutoMapper.  You could simply return a static list if you prefer.

Comment: thanks for quick reply. writing list code in get is nice idea but if we select it more than once, would it result in two separate queries. i know list is usually called on view once, just asking for curiosity!

Comment: @Muhammad: I believe the answer to your question is that it depends.  In my case, I have an entity with a list of child objects that has already been created.  I use AutoMapper to copy the entity's data to the view model.  When I query the view model's list, there is no database interactivity.  However, if you relied on IQueryable it is possible that a query against a list could result in a database query.  Same thing can be said if you build your list by hitting the repository directly - in that case maybe you could use the view model's constructor to populate the local list once?

Answer (score 10):

Why not follow the convention which I reckon the majority of people use? You have coupled your ViewModel to your repo which I would also recommend changing. By putting the repo.GetStatuses inside your Controller/Action is simple and it works. I also prefer putting the SelectList inside my view and have the ViewModel house the list of items - but that's my personal preference. You can then clearly see/understand what type of objects your ViewModel deals with. DRY is a principle not a requirement.

**ViewModel**

```
public VMPosition
{
    public int StatusId { get; set; }
    public IList<Status> StatusList { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult UpdatePosition(int id)
{
    var model = new VMPosition(id);
    model.StatusList = _repo.getStatuses;
    return View(model);
}

public ActionResult UpdatePosition(int id, VMPosition Position)
{
    if(!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        Position.StatusList = _repo.getStatuses;
        return View(Position);
    }
    ...
}
```

**View**

```
<%= Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.StatusId, new SelectList(Model.StatusList)...
```

**Edit - Refactor PopulateSelectLists**

```
public ActionResult UpdatePosition(int id)
{
    var model = new VMPosition(id);
    PopulateSelectLists(model);
    return View(model);
}

public ActionResult UpdatePosition(int id, VMPosition Position)
{
    if(!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        PopulateSelectLists(Position);
        return View(Position);
    }
    ...
}

private void PopulateSelectLists(VMPosition Position)
{
    Position.StatusList = _repo.GetStatuses;
    Position.OtherSelectList = ...
    ...
}
```

Comment: suppose we have 4 to 5 select lists on ur page that i do have on mine. with your approach we will end up writing populating code for lists twice in either (getand post) actionresult. however i like idea of decoupling repository from viewmodel. the question is how can i do this in best possible way.

Comment: The web is a stateless model. I don't see it as a problem that you are retrieving the same information in different ActionResult's as these are two separate requests. If you are concerned about duplication of code then refactor your ActionResult's to return the statuses - therefore you've only written the code once.